# Unable to determine object's concavity in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am attempting to detect convex pentagons in an image using OpenCV. I am using the following image:

[image]

I first find the contours in the image and then do this:

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * perimeter, True)
isPentagon = len(approx) == 5
```

When I ran this on the image, I got this result:

[image]

This white part in the image is being detected. I thought that checking the concavity would solve it. Here is what I attempted:

```
isPentagon = len(approx) == 5 and cv2.isContourConvex(c)
```

However, for all the pentagons I tried, `isContourConvex` returned `False`. I am not sure why. I tried other images as well and the same happened. Variable `c` is the contour.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe a better way to check if a polygon is regular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues was that I was passing in the original contour found by `cv2.findContours` into the `cv2.isContourConvex`. That original contour has a ton of points, some of which give the shape a concave characteristic.

To fix this, I had to call `cv2.isContourConvex(approx)`. This would evaluate the approximation of the pentagon that has exactly five sides and five vertices. Although I would later draw the initial contour, evaluating the contourConvex function on the approximation yielded the correct result.